# Mod_rewrite - redirecting an already rewritten url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I had previously rewritten the URL for articles this way:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?article_(.*)_(.*).html$ index.php?sectionpp=$1&sectionpp2=$2&content=article&artid=$3&curbigart=$4 [L]
```

This produced the url like:
http://www.domain.com/Entertainment/114194/VINYETTE-TO-RELEASE-DEBUT-ALBUM-ON-MAY-7-2013

However, now I have redesigned the site and made the urls shorter:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?sectionpp=$1&content=article&artid=$2&curbigart=$3 [L]
```

Which produces url like:
http://www.domain.com/Entertainment/114194

The QUESTION:
Is it possible to redirect the already rewritten url
http://domain.com/Entertainment/114194/VINYETTE-TO-RELEASE-DEBUT-ALBUM-ON-MAY-7-2013

to

http://domain.com/Entertainment/114194

And obviously we're not talking about single page, but thousands, so good one line in .htaccess would be needed hehe. I know I could simply redirect in php, but I assume there must be a way to do that in .htaccess as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to redirect the already rewritten url `domain.com/Entertainment/114194/VINYETTE-TO-RELEASE-DEBUT-ALBUM-ON-MAY-7-2013`
>   to `domain.com/Entertainment/114194`

You can use rule as very first rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/\d+)/.+$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's almost there. It's now works on the entertainment category. But the Entertainment is actually a variable as well.How would you change it to make that work as well?